# what if i pass categorical value for ML.Net prediction never passed before

Tags: ml.net

for example, if I trained the model for these values

```
Column1 = A , Column2 = B , Column3 = C , Label = 10 
Column1 = D , Column2 = E , Column3 = F , Label = 20
Column1 = G , Column2 = H , Column3 = I , Label = 30
```

What if i want to predict?

```
Column1 = A , Column2 = B , Column3 = Z
```

what the model do for that?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you process the categorical data.
If, for example, you used dictionary-based one-hot vectorizer:

```
new CategoricalOneHotVectorizer("Column2", "Column2", "Column3")
```

then the model will build a dictionary of terms per column:
Column1 -> [A, D, G]
Column2 -> [B, E, H]
Column3 -> [C, F, I]

If the value has not been seen (is not present in a dictionary), the `CategoricalOneHotVectorizer` assigns zero to all the 'one-hot' slots. So your example `A B Z` will turn into `1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0`.

If, on the other hand, you use hash-based one-hot encoding:

```
new CategoricalHashOneHotVectorizer("Column2", "Column2", "Column3")
```

the incoming value Z will be hashed in the same way as the seen values C, F and I, and this will activate one of the `2^HashBits` slots of the output column, based on the value of the hash.

The [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.transforms.categoricalonehotvectorizer?view=ml-dotnet) on the `CategoricalOneHotVectorizer` is not very clear on this one, but it still says:

> The Key value is the one-based index of the slot set in the Ind/Bag options. If the Key option is not found, it is assigned the value zero.

Comment: I created an issue on the ML.NET Github page to clarify the docs. https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/675